# Call methods overridden in subclass from superclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance

I have a base class that has class methods defined for returning various pieces of information that I use to build service url's.  The base class also has an instance method defined for building that URL.  I would like the base class to have a default implementation of this method, so that I only have to override it in my subclasses when I need the url to be different.  How do I have this base method call the overridden class methods to build the url using the class methods from the subclass?  Below is the code I have now that is not working:

The base class method:

```
- (NSString *)buildRequestUrlString{
    return [Utils serviceEndpointForOperationId:[[self class]operationId] version:[[self class] operationVersion] andRequestMethod:[[self class] methodType];
}
```

operationId, operationVersion and methodType are the class methods that are implemented in the subclass, but when the subclass makes the following call:

```
[super buildRequestUrlString];
```

It is using the class methods from the base class to build my endpoint, and not the class methods in my subclass.  How do I make it not do that?  Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the template pattern for this. Basically create 3 instance methods in your base class to get your operationId, etc. in the base class they just return nil. Then in your subclasses override these 3 methods to return the correct values.

Your buildRequestUrlString method uses the [self operationId] etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I did except they aren't instance methods, they are class methods.  This would be working if they were instance methods, but I couldn't use instance methods because I'm using these methods for other things in other places, and instance methods won't work in those cases.

Comment: After going back and looking at this, I realized that I had forgotten to override the three class methods.  That was why it was defaulting to the base implementation of those three class methods.  Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `self` instead of `super`.

```
[self buildRequestUrlString];
```

(Or explain why that doesn't work in your case).

Responding to the comment, it sounds like your class decomposition is incorrect (or you are confused).  Specifically, this is likely why you've received three answers that were all "use `self`";   we don't understand where the problem is.

If your base class needs to call an instance method from a subclass, then it needs a reference to an instance of the subclass.  I.e. say you have:

```
@interface Concrete:Base
```

Then, Base might implement a class method like:

```
+ baseWithConcreteQuantity:(int)aQuant
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithConcreteQuantity:aQuant];
}
```

And it would be used like:

```
[Concrete baseWithConcreteQuantity:10];
```

That is, class methods in Objective-C -- unlike static methods in other languages -- are inherited just like instance methods.

Now, as for the instance method, you always call `super`'s implementation of a particular method from that method.   Using `super` to call a *different* method of the base class is pretty much *never* done and is a sure sign that something else is wrong.

Similarly, the base class should never try to specifically call functionality in a subclass that doesn't exist in the base.

I.e.

```
// in base
...
[self doSomething];
...

- (void)doSomething { ; }

// where a subclass might
- (void)doSomething { ... ; [super doSomething]; }
```

Comment: This won't work because this would then be a recursive call.  What I want to happen is to define the default behavior of this method in the super class.  When the method is actually called on the subclass, since the subclass doesn't have a definition for buildRequestUrlString, it will use the super classes default implementation of this method.  But in the super classes default implementation, I want it to use the sub classes overridden versions of the class methods operationId, opeartionVersion and methodType.

Answer (score 0):

In your "buildRequestUrlString"-method your [self class] is obviously of type "base class".

Object Inheritance Guidelines would strongly disagree with trying to access properties of subclasses from your father-class, since the father-class has (and should have) no knowledge whether subclasses even exist.

Guess, I don't type fast enough, to solve this do what bbum said ;)

EDIT: This'd be a hack, and against what I just said, but you could hand over the class-name as an argument:

```
- (NSString *)buildRequestUrlString:(Class)theClass{
    if (!theClass) theClass = [self class];
    return [Utils serviceEndpointForOperationId:[theClass operationId] version:[theClass operationVersion] andRequestMethod:[theClass methodType]];
}

[super buildRequestUrlString:[self class]];
```

Comment: bbum's answer was not what I was looking for, so don't feel bad :)  The methods that I want to call in the subclass are defined in the superclass.  I just want the superclass to use the overridden version's of those methods.  The whole idea behind what I'm trying to accomplish is to not duplicate the same code over and over again for each of my subclasses that need to use the default implementation of this method.  This is very easy to do in C# and just works out of the box.

Comment: I thought of that as a solution, but I agree, that would be a hack.  Is there some way to determine the type of class that is actually executing a method, inside of that method?  If I could do that, I could probably make this work.

Comment: well, if you run [self Class] in any method you get the current class this method is run on... I could misunderstand you, if so sorry for the obvious answer...

Comment: PS: If in doubt, take a large piece of paper and paint some graphs/uml-diagrams, to get your mind organized, that's what I always do!